# Is there a way to identify platform.resume event was called by camera?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have an issue with my ionic v2 app, I have subscribed to `platform.resume` on `app.component.ts` where I have an redirection, based on user status, every time a picture is taken and app returns from camera `platform.resume` is called and the redirection breaks my app flow. Is there a way to identify `resume` event called by `cordova-plugin-camera`?

Comment: I cant think of a use case where you would redirect based on platform.resume..

Comment: Token validation, redirects back to login page

Comment: I generally use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) for triggering such actions. I never used platform resume

Answer (score 1):

> Token validation, redirects back to login page

I suggest you use [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) for triggering redirection based on login/logout

```
 events.publish('token:received', token);
```

and in your app.component.ts

```
events.subscribe('token:received',(token)=>{
  //redirect
});
```

An internal function like `platform.resume` may be used internally by any number of plugins or components.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive suggestion, I'll test it tomorrow morning

Comment: Do you know if there is some kind of param or identifier used by `cordova-camera-plugin` that I could actually use on resume? I think it would be a usable feature, if it exists.

Comment: I did find https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/24d0052541a31d3dd651780c29fdd1c2e67fa6ee/src/platform/platform-registry.ts#L201 it looks like any cordova plugin can interact with ionic through platform lifecycle hooks

Comment: It makes sense. plugins need to used within platform.ready() anyway

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, you can use the returned promise and then redirect to another page.

```
Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.NavCtrl.push(TheRedirectPage, ParamsYouDLikeToPass);
  // i think you can also call platform.resume here, if you want, but i'd stick with the promise return.
}, (err) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

There's no need to check with the `platform.resume`, since when it returns from camera it's all ready for you to do your stuff.

Comment: I don't call platform.resume on camera response, I have subscribed to it on `app.component.ts` so it gets called indirectly.